# How to download sub pages linked by javascript function in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am going to download all pages linked by javascript function.
The HTML structure is following.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function a(){
        document.location = 'a.html'
      }
      function b(){
        document.location = 'b.html'
      }
      function c(){
        document.location = 'c.html'
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:a()">Item a</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:b()">Item b</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:c()">Item c</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

`a.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <h1>Item A</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function d(){
        document.location = 'd.html'
      }
      function e(){
        document.location = 'e.html'
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:d()">Item d</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:e()">Item e</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

`b.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Item B</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

`c.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Item C</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

`d.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Item D</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

`e.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function d(){
        document.location = 'd.html'
      }
      function b(){
        document.location = 'b.html'
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Item E</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:d()">Item d</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:b()">Item b</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the best way to download all pages?

Comment: What you have tried so far? And I see you [haven't accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14551577/le-thanh-thai?tab=questions)

Comment: There are a lot of ways. You can crawl all link and then utilize existing webdriver via function like ```driver.page_source``` to write them into HTML files. Alternatively, you can utilize Python package like ```requests``` or even ```urlib``` to do HTTP request and save them into HTML files.  More context is needed to determine which is the best way.

Comment: `a` tags are linked in javascript function, not URL. And I described the js function is same to linked html file name here. But it is different in real case. The important thing I want to say is that you will not know which page is linked to without clicking on the `a` tag. In that case, what is the best way?